# How to rearrange dataset using pivot in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and I am trying to write an SQL query to rearrange the below data using pivot or any other approach and I am not sure how or if it's doable. Its a transaction table that relates to withdrawals, where a reference(`ref`) number is common to a transaction which starts from withdrawpending to withdraw

table name: Lex

| id | Amount1 | Amount2 | ref | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 | -240 | 100 | withdraw |
| 001 | -240 | 240 | 100 | withdrawpending |

what I want to achieve

| id | withdrawpending | withdraw | ref |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 240 | -240 | 100 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like following (no values in id2 for withdraw hence null, vice-versa for id1 and withdrawpending) -

```
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select * from lex;
+----+--------+---------+-----+-----------------+
| ID | AMOUNT | AMOUNT2 | REF | TYPE            |
|----+--------+---------+-----+-----------------|
|  1 |      0 |    -240 | 100 | withdraw        |
|  2 |   -240 |     240 | 100 | withdrawpending |
+----+--------+---------+-----+-----------------+
2 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.163s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select id,"'withdraw'" as withdraw,"'withdrawpending'" as withdrawpending,ref from
                                      (select id,amount2,ref, type from lex) tab1 pivot (min(amount2) for type in ('wit
                                     hdraw','withdrawpending')) as P;
+----+----------+-----------------+-----+
| ID | WITHDRAW | WITHDRAWPENDING | REF |
|----+----------+-----------------+-----|
|  1 |     -240 |            NULL | 100 |
|  2 |     NULL |             240 | 100 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-----+
2 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.141s
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with selective summation via IFF & SUM

```
SELECT 
    t.id,
    t.ref,
    sum(iff(t.type='withdrawpending', t.amount2, 0)) as withdrawpending,
    sum(iff(t.type='withdraw', t.amount2, 0)) as withdraw
FROM VALUES
    ('001', 0, -240, 100, 'withdraw'),
    ('001', -240, 240,100, 'withdrawpending')
    t(id, Amount1, Amount2, ref, type)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

which gives:

| ID | REF | WITHDRAWPENDING | WITHDRAW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 100 | 240 | -240 |